# Scan for wireless network in system running through virtual box

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, virtualbox

Following [scan for network](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Scan_for_Wireless_Network)  link to list all nearby wifi signal available around me but inside

```
$ls /sys/class/net
.  ..  enp0s3  lo
```

I found only these two files.

- Why the wifi files are not there because my laptop has a wifi card?
- Is there any alternative way to list near by wifi devices in ubuntu?

Comment: If Ubuntu is the Guest OS you will need a USB wifi card to access wifi

Comment: Two OS cannot control the same hardware simultaneously. Networking, including WiFi, belongs to the VM Host (not Guest). A network connection shared to the VM Guest is presented as an ethernet connection, regardless of the actual connection method. You can use VirtualBox's USB pass-through to directly control a Wi-Fi USB dongle, but it's usually faster and simpler for most users to simply tweak your VirtualBox application settings on the Host.